# XSLT to transform Request XML to Response XML

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have a request Xml:

```
<quoteDetails>
<q2cNumber>Q-0749</q2cNumber>
<quoteNumber>1</quoteNumber>
<changeOrderRevisionNumber>0</changeOrderRevisionNumber>
<spdRevisionNumber>0</spdRevisionNumber>
<authorizeEligible>Y</authorizeEligible>
<userCountryCode>US</userCountryCode>
<primaryMarketingId>MKR345</primaryMarketingId>
<intExtSrcInd>I</intExtSrcInd>
<porposalName>Test926</porposalName>
</quoteDetails>
```

And my response should look like:

```
<quoteDetails>Q-0749,1,0,0,Y,US,MKR345,I,Test926</quoteDetails>
```

How to fetch the above response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="QuoteDetails">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=","/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```